# TypeError: list_content() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'

Tags: python, class

I have a python problem that creates a box and puts items in the box and with the help of the list command I can see what's in my box. One example of the execution may go as:

next command> newbox bedroom-box-05

next command> add bedroom-box-05 pillow 3

next command> list bedroom-box-05

Box "bedroom-box-05" contains 3 items.

3 pillow

There are some issues with class MovingBox() as I cannot change the main functions.

```
class MovingBox():
"""A class for keeping track of the contents ofa moving box. """
def __init__(self,*args):
    self = dict()

def add_item(self,key,value =[]):
    setattr(self,key,value)
    self.add_item=value

def list_content(self,key,value =[]):
    setattr(self, key, value)
    self.list_content = value

    key1 = Keys()  # parens
    key1.list_content(value)
```

###### DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING AFTER THIS LINE

```
def convert_str_to_int(word):
"""
Converts the parameter string *word* in to an integer value.
"""
try:
    result = int(word)
except ValueError:
    return None

return result
def newbox(all_boxes, list_of_additional_info):

if len(list_of_additional_info) != 1:
    print("Error: wrong number of initial data: can't create a new box.")
    return

box_name = list_of_additional_info[0]
all_boxes[box_name] = MovingBox(box_name)

def add_to_box(all_boxes, list_of_additional_info):

if len(list_of_additional_info) != 3:
    print("Error: wrong number of elements: can't add into a box.")
    return

box_name, item_name, item_count = list_of_additional_info
item_count = convert_str_to_int(item_count)

if item_count is None:
    print("Error: not a number: can't add to a box.")
    return

if box_name not in all_boxes:
    print("Error: box does not exist: can't add to a box.")
    return
all_boxes[box_name].add_item(item_name, item_count)
def list_box_content(all_boxes, list_of_additional_info):
"""Displays the contents of a single box in *all_boxes* """
if len(list_of_additional_info) != 1:
    print("Error: wrong number of elements: can't list contents.")
    return

box_name = list_of_additional_info[0]

if box_name not in all_boxes:
    print("Error: box does not exist: can't list content.")
    return
all_boxes[box_name].list_content()
def main():

    boxes = {}

while True:
    command_line = input("next command> ").strip()
    if command_line == "":
        break

    command_words = command_line.split()
    first_word = command_words[0]
    list_of_other_words = command_words[1:]

    if first_word == "quit":
        break

    elif first_word == "newbox":
        newbox(boxes, list_of_other_words)

    elif first_word == "add":
        add_to_box(boxes, list_of_other_words)

    elif first_word == "list":
        list_box_content(boxes, list_of_other_words)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Don't use an attribut with the same name as a method of the same class `self.list_content = `

Comment: You call `.list_content()` and the definition is `def list_content(self,key,value =[]):`, so the error is clear : where is the `key` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot change the main functions."?  `MovingBox` only has two methods -- which ones are you allowed to change?  (The entire implementation looks really bad IMO -- if your teacher is telling you to use `setattr` instead of teaching you about dicts they're doing you a severe disservice!)

Comment: @Samwise I can change the MovingBox, but nothing after that..

Comment: Did you get any sort of instructions on what MovingBox's methods are, or are you supposed to just figure it out from the rest of the code?

Comment: @Samwise no suggestions were given , I need to find out myself

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way this class is being used in the code that you're not supposed to change, I don't think you've understood what the `MovingBox` is supposed to contain/model.  Here are examples of how `MovingBox` is being used:

```
MovingBox(box_name)
# creates a box named box_name

all_boxes[box_name].add_item(item_name, item_count)
# increments the count of item_name by item_count

all_boxes[box_name].list_content()
# lists the content of the box
```

The immediate error you're hitting is that `list_content` isn't supposed to take a parameter, but the larger problem is that what you've tried to implement doesn't match up at all with what the rest of the code is trying to do -- e.g. your implementation of `add_item` seems to be trying to add a unique item with an arbitrary value (that defaults to `[]`, which has its own problems), when the calling code is actually providing a **count** of a **type** of item.

Since `MovingBox` is seemingly supposed to just be a counter with a custom interface, I'd implement it as a wrapper around `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

class MovingBox():
    """A class for keeping track of the contents of a moving box. """
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name
        self.contents = Counter()
        
    def add_item(self, name: str, count: int) -> None:
        self.contents[name] += count

    def list_content(self) -> None:
        total = sum(self.contents.values())
        print(f'Box "{self.name}" contains {total} items.')
        for name, count in self.contents.items():
            print(f'{count} {name}')
```

```
>>> box = MovingBox("a box")
>>> box.add_item("pillow", 3)
>>> box.list_content()
Box "a box" contains 3 items.
3 pillow
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use collections library

Comment: I figured as much, and I didn't want to actually just straight-up do your homework for you.  ;) Hopefully now that you have a working example of what the code is *supposed* to be doing you'll be able to fix the implementation on your own to comply with the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: I understand, But i can approach without using library functions right?and could you please tell me what "None" is doing here?

Comment: Yes, you can make this work without `Counter` by changing only two lines of code.  (Hint: read up on how `dict`s work!)  `-> None` is an annotation to indicate that a function doesn't return anything.  It doesn't actually change anything about how the function works when you call it, but works like a comment to tell the reader (and also some tools, like static type analyzers and linters) that this function isn't supposed/expected to return a value.